# Java Eclipse. Xstream library classpath error keeps showing up

Tags: java, xstream

I am trying to generate an XML file with Xsteam lib.
Every time I try to use the lib this error shows up :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream

Help, please.

Comment: Which means the lib isn't on your classpath. You will need to add it.

Comment: THANK YOU. 
Turns out I had the library in the module path that's why the error shows up.
A simple drag and drop solved my problem of 2 damn weeks. 

I owe u a coffffeeee <3